# How can I solve the JSON error with running npm install?

Tags: node.js

I am getting a JSON error when I run `npm install` inside my project to install dependencies.

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...EsfB30RyD1HUtFKPTfwVO'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/yogesh/.npm/_logs/2019-09-19T16_54_23_816Z-debug.log
```

I have tried clearing the cache but nothing happened.

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Also to reinstall the nodejs and all the things, but nothing solved.

Here's my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.7",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

**How can I resolve this?**

Comment: can u post the package json file?

Comment: @siddharth-pa
Added it

Comment: Could you also post the full output of `npm install` ?

Comment: @Evert Added it

Comment: @YogeshDeveloper is that everything? This is super strange. Do you have a package-lock.json file and could you try deleting it?

Comment: @Evert No I don't have it

Comment: can u try with deleting node_modules and reinstall again. are u using windows?

Comment: What about the contents of: `/home/yogesh/.npm/_logs/2019-09-19T16_54_23_816Z-debug.log` ?

Comment: @SiddharthPal Ubuntu 19.04, doesn't have node_modules

Comment: @Evert It's a bit long file

Comment: @YogeshDeveloper you could post it to pastebin or gist.github.com

Comment: @Evert https://gist.github.com/yogesh-aggarwal/daf42936d36304db7906273bef10a4d2 | Link to gist

Comment: The error appears to be thrown because of this package `babel/plugin-transform-computed-properties@^7.2.0`

Comment: @Evet What should I do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199696/discussion-between-yogesh-developer-and-evert).

Comment: @YogeshDeveloper Try to reinstall node maybe ? Wich version your projects needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just uninstall & reinstall you angular cli. After clearing the cache of npm

```
npm cache clean --force

npm uninstall @angular/cli
npm install @angular/cli
```

**This will solve your problem.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Vuejs then you want to install the latest nodejs package.

There are commands you run in your terminal -

`curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh -o install_nvm.sh`

`nano install_nvm.sh`

`bash install_nvm.sh`

`nvm ls-remote`

`nvm install` latest-version

`nvm use` latest-version

`node -v`

**This will solve your problem.**